# Android playing audio output to handset, but has no sound in earphone plugged in

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

Android AudioManager and output is quite difficult to understand. I am checking AudioManager api and also search for some explanation. But the scenario i want is not working the way i want.

I have the local downloaded audio file. First I play them as STREAM_MUSIC. So the sound will output to the phone speaker and when earphone plugged in, it will played through the earphone.

But i was requested to output the audio file to handset instead of the speaker. 
There is no easy way to change it. I set audioManager.setSpeakerPhoneOn(false), the audio is still playing output through the speaker.

So after studying, i modified as below:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioManager.requestAudioFocus(mFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

By changing the audioManager mode to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION (like the phone call), the audio file is finally output to handset. But when i plugged in the earphone, i didn't hear sound from the earphone, and i don't find the api to set the output route to handset manually in the AudioManager.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Finally, i know the cause. When plugged in earphone, it is to adjust the media volume not the phone volume. But it makes me very confuse.

Comment: How stupid i am. It is not the audio manager mode issue.  I finally changed the Mediaplayer set stream type and everything works. Sorry for asking.